# How to link slider inputs?

Tags: r, shiny

How to link slider inputs in a way that sum of slider inputs must be 100?

The following code consists of 3 slider inputs which are independent of each other and each slider input can reach 100. But I want these three sliders not to exceed the sum of 100 together.
The sum of all slider inputs must be 100. e.g. 33/33/34 or 0/50/50,...

consequently, the result of following code should reach a maximum of 1

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("3 slider percentage"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(fluidRow(
                             column(width = 6, 
                                    selectInput("value_1", "value 1", selected=5, 1:10)
                             ),
                             column(width = 6,
                                    sliderInput("perc_1", "perc 1", value = 33, min = 0.00, max = 100, step = 1)
                             ),
                             column(width = 6, 
                                    selectInput("value_2", "value 2", selected=5, 1:10)
                             ),
                             column(width = 6,
                                    sliderInput("perc_2", "perc 2", value = 33, min = 0.00, max = 100, step = 1)
                             ),
                             column(width = 6, 
                                    selectInput("value_3", "value 3", selected=5, 1:10)
                             ),
                             column(width = 6,
                                    sliderInput("perc_3", "perc 3", value = 33, min = 0.00, max = 100, step = 1)
                             )
                           )
      ),
     
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      
      tableOutput("result")
      
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$result <- renderTable({
    (( as.numeric(input$value_1) / 10 * as.numeric(input$perc_1) / 100 ) + ( as.numeric(input$value_2) / 10 * as.numeric(input$perc_2) / 100 )  + ( as.numeric(input$value_3) / 10 * as.numeric(input$perc_3) / 100 ))
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: "The following code consists of 3 slider inputs which are independent of each other ... The sum of all slider inputs must be 100".  That's inherently contradictory.  You need to define how a change in one of the slider inputs should affect each of the other two.  One option is to use only *two* sliders and calculate the "remainder" when the sum of the slider inputs is <=100.  You, would of course, need to define behaviour when the sum of the two sliders *exceeds* 100.

Comment: I understand that it might be not very compehensibly, it`s also hard to formulate... How could this definition of how one slider effects the others look like? It should be 3 sliders. Well if one slider value changes the values of the other sliders should adapt. Up to any possible rule.

Comment: Another idea.  Use a *single* `sliderInput`,  with limits of 0 and 100 and which displays a range.  For example `sliderInput("slider", label = "Slider Range", min = 0,  max = 100, value = c(40, 60))`.  The two cut points define the three values you need and you are guaranteed that they sum to 100.  (If the cuts are x and y, your values are x, y-x and 100-y).  In the snippet, your values would be 40, 20 (60 - 40) and 40 (100-60).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works, but this was the idea I had. This is building off of the comment of @Limey. There are three `observeEvent` I put in, and I `disabled` using `shinyjs`the slider `input$perc_3`, since I couldn't think of a way to manually adjust that slider without frustrating users.

1. Check both `input$perc_1` and `input$perc_2`. If these add up to less than 100, then make `input$perc_3` the remainder
2. Check `input$perc_1`. If this and `input$perc_2` add up to over 100, then reduce `input$perc_2`.
3. Similar to above, but check `input$perc_2`. If this and `input$perc_1` add up to over 100, then reduce `input$perc_1`.

Also note, for my readability I blocked out the value inputs, since they didn't seem necessary to answer the question. Also, just to make sure things were adding to 100, I put in a `textOutput` to add the percentages together. Hopefully this helps and points you in the right direction. This was a fun exercise!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  # Application title
  titlePanel("3 slider percentage"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(fluidRow(
      # column(width = 6, 
      #        selectInput("value_1", "value 1", selected=5, 1:10)
      # ),
      column(width = 6,
             sliderInput("perc_1", "perc 1", value = 33, min = 0.00, max = 100, step = 1)
      ),
      # column(width = 6, 
      #        selectInput("value_2", "value 2", selected=5, 1:10)
      # ),
      column(width = 6,
             sliderInput("perc_2", "perc 2", value = 33, min = 0.00, max = 100, step = 1)
      ),
      # column(width = 6, 
      #        selectInput("value_3", "value 3", selected=5, 1:10)
      # ),
      column(width = 6,
             disabled(sliderInput("perc_3", "perc 3", value = 33, min = 0.00, max = 100, step = 1))
      )
    )
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("SUM"),
      tableOutput("result")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(c(input$perc_1,input$perc_2), {
    updateSliderInput(session, "perc_3", value = (100-input$perc_1-input$perc_2))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$perc_1, {
    if(input$perc_2 > (100-input$perc_1)) {
    updateSliderInput(session, "perc_2", value = (100-input$perc_1))
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$perc_2, {
    if(input$perc_1 > (100-input$perc_2)) {
      updateSliderInput(session, "perc_1", value = (100-input$perc_2))
    }
  })
  output$SUM<-renderText(sum(input$perc_1, input$perc_2, input$perc_3))
  
  # output$result <- renderTable({
  #   (( as.numeric(input$value_1) / 10 * as.numeric(input$perc_1) / 100 ) + 
  #      ( as.numeric(input$value_2) / 10 * as.numeric(input$perc_2) / 100 )  + 
  #      ( as.numeric(input$value_3) / 10 * as.numeric(input$perc_3) / 100 ))
  # })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```